# How to uninstall Mongoose OS from Debian?

Tags: debian, uninstall

I installed [Mongoose OS](https://mongoose-os.com/) using the following command on Debian 9.5.0:

```
curl -fsSL https://mongoose-os.com/downloads/mos/install.sh | /bin/bash
```

How do I safely **uninstall** this software?

Comment: It's really not recommendable to do `curl | sh` like commands, especially not as root. The only limits to what a script executed liked that can do, is what the user you excuted it as can do, and there's no general way to undo what it does. A quick look at this script suggests to me that it only downloads one file and puts it in `~/.mos` so deleting that should be okay (but it's nearly 2 in the night here - having an issue at work, waiting for a network guy to debug it - so I might be wrong)

Comment: Thanks Henrick. The official site (https://mongoose-os.com/software.html) advised to do that. Looking for an expert advice.

Comment: Unfortunately “official sites” don’t always give good advice :-/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine how to uninstall a piece of software installed in this fashion, you need to read through the script used to perform the installation and determine what it did, then undo that. Using `curl | sh`-style patterns means that the installation script isn’t preserved, so we need to download the current version and hope that its behaviour hasn’t changed since the installation.

In this particular case, uninstallation is straightforward, assuming defaults:

- delete `~/.mos/bin/mos` — that’s the only file added during installation;
- if `~/.mos/bin` is empty, delete it, and then if `~/.mos` is empty, delete it;
- edit `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` to remove the line adding `~/.mos/bin` to the `PATH`.

If you specified a different `DESTDIR` when installing, then you’ll need to remove `mos` from that directory instead.